# Ist der Code of Conduct in allen SE Gruppen identisch?

Tags: support, help-center

Ich bin relativ neu hier, d.h. seit knapp einem Monat und hauptsächlich in der Gruppe *Music Practice and Theory*.

Dort habe ich eben im Help Center nach dem [Code of Conduct](https://music.stackexchange.com/conduct) geschaut, dabei ist mir aufgefallen, dass das Layout ähnlich ist, wenn er nicht sogar völlig gleich ist.

Bevor ich mich nun durch sämtliche Communities durchchecke, frage ich hier:
**Ist der Code of Conduct in allen SE-Gruppen identisch?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standardmäßig sind bis auf [What topics can I ask about here?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) und Teile der [Tour](http://german.stackexchange.com/tour) alle Hilfeseiten für alle Stack-Exchange-Seiten gleich. Es gibt ein paar Ausnahmen für spezielle Seiten (zum Beispiel, Stack Overflow zum [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), aber diese drehen sich um spezielle inhaltliche Ansprüche der Seite.

Die vermutlich aktuellste offizielle Verkündung zum Code of Conduct findest Du [hier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/255554). Sie betrifft offensichtlicherweise alle Seiten.